# Can't access DBpedia thumbnails

Tags: uri, sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am trying through my application to retrieve the value of thumbnail property and display the image. I don't know the structure of the URI in order to create the link for the image. So I went to the page of the resources (example: [`http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Henrik_Ibsen`](http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Henrik_Ibsen) =>
[`http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Henrik_Ibsen_by_Gustav_Borgen_NFB-19778_restored.jpg?width=300`](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Henrik_Ibsen_by_Gustav_Borgen_NFB-19778_restored.jpg?width=300)) and I clicked on the link of the value of thumbnail property but it takes me to an 404 page (error, page do not exist). All of them takes to the same error page. Is it a problem with DBpedia? do you know to which URI I should append the value of thumbnail to (in order to get the link for the actual image)?

[Other examples of inaccessible DBpedia thumbnails](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20%3Fs%20%3Fo%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fs%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fthumbnail%3E%20%3Fo%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010)

Thanks.

Comment: For me the link to the image works.

Comment: Worth noting – these are not DBpedia images. They are Wikipedia images, to which DBpedia just provides links. The reported issue appears to have been with WIkipedia/Wikimedia, not DBpedia. Also, this question was echoed on [DBpedia's Confluence](https://dbpedia.atlassian.net/wiki/questions/7859558/cant-access-dbpedia-thumbnails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by playing with the links. I replaced "commons" with "en" and I reduced the pixels. Then suddenly 80% of the images link that were broken become accessible.

```
image= image.trim();
image= image.replace("commons", "en");
image= image.replaceAll("(jpg/)[^&]*(px)", "$1100$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no "URI structure" to use for such depictions/thumbnails; that's part of why there's a property to hold the links to them.

Clicking the links on the SNORQL page just keep you rolling through SNORQL pages; [this SPARQL query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+%3Fs+%3Fo+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A%3Fs+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fthumbnail%3E+%3Fo%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder+by+%3Fs%0D%0Alimit+10&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) --

```
SELECT ?s ?o WHERE {
?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail> ?o
}
order by ?s
limit 10
```

-- and [its results page](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fs+%3Fo+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A%3Fs+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Fthumbnail%3E+%3Fo%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder+by+%3Fs%0D%0Alimit+10&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) let you click directly to the images.  (I've added an `ORDER BY`, so you're *probably* seeing the same 10 solutions as I am.)

On dereference, the thumbnail links take you through a couple of redirects in every case, like --

[`http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Eddie_Collins_1911.jpg?width=300`](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Eddie_Collins_1911.jpg?width=300)

-- takes you to --

[`https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Eddie_Collins_1911.jpg/300px-Eddie_Collins_1911.jpg`](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Eddie_Collins_1911.jpg/300px-Eddie_Collins_1911.jpg)

The last solution I see may be an example of what you're seeing as a problem --

**s** [`http://dbpedia.org/resource/%22Dr._Death%22_Steve_Williams`](http://live.dbpedia.org/resource/%22Dr._Death%22_Steve_Williams)

**o** [`http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Steve_Williams.jpg?width=300`](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Steve_Williams.jpg?width=300)

This link [stalls partway through the redirects](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Redirect/file/Steve_Williams.jpg&width=300), without bringing an actual thumbnail, because the "Steve_Williams.jpg" doesn't exist -- possibly because it's been deleted, wasn't uploaded, there was a typo in the page editing, etc.